# Filter out vertices that have outgoing edges to other vertices that are NOT in a specified list of values (SPARQL)

Tags: graph, sparql, rdf, amazon-neptune

I'm using SPARQL for RDF and am having trouble coming up with a query that will allow me to filter out all vertices that have edges to other vertices that are not in a list of specified values.

Here is a visual representation of the graph I'm working with, which contains nodes of two separate RDF types (`:package` and `:platform`). In this graph, packages (`:Package_A`, `:Package_B`, `:Package_C`, and `:Package_D`) have outgoing edges to each platform that they require, and the values of the platforms are `:Platform_1:` and `:Platform_2`:
[image]

Here is the data that creates this graph:

```
INSERT DATA {
   :Package_A             rdf:type   :package .
   :Package_B             rdf:type   :package .
   :Package_C             rdf:type   :package .
   :Package_D             rdf:type   :package .

   :Platform_1            rdf:type   :platform .
   :Platform_2            rdf:type   :platform .

   :Package_A             :platform  :Platform_1 .
   :Package_B             :platform  :Platform_1 .
   :Package_C             :platform  :Platform_1 .
   :Package_D             :platform  :Platform_1 . 

   :Package_D             :platform  :Platform_2 .
}
```

I would like to form a query that is able to return all vertices with rdf:type = :package, but i would like to exclude all packages that have any outgoing edges to a platform that is not in a list of specified platform values.

For example, in the case of this specified singleton list:
`[:Platform_1]`

`Package_A`, `Package_B` and `Package_C` should be returned since these packages *only* have edges that lead to `Platform_1`.

While `Package_D` should get filtered out since it contains edges to both `Platform_1` AND `Platform_2` (and `Platform_2` is not in the specified list).

So far, I have attempted this query using a `FILTER`, which doesn't work, as `Package_D` is still returned by it:

```
SELECT * {
    ?package a :package .
    ?package :platform ?platform .
    FILTER(:platform NOT IN(:Platform_1))
}
```

Anyone have any ideas how I could form a query that would exclude any vertices that have edges to values that are not in the list (in this case, any edge that leads to `Platform_2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that the filter condition succeeds if *any* platform vertice matches the condition. You get back `Package_D` because one of the platforms is `:Platform_2`, which is not in the list `(:Platform_1)` - so the condition succeeds.

What you need instead is a filter condition that checks if *none* of the matching platforms are in the list. For this purpose, SPARQL has the `NOT EXISTS` condition, which takes a graph pattern as an argument:

```
?package a :package.
FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?package :platform ?platform. 
                    FILTER (?platform IN(:Platform_1)) }
```

Literally says: "give me back packages for which no platform exists that is in the supplied list:".

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! I was actually going for a query that says "give me back packages for which platforms _only_ exists in the supplied list" (so in this case, Package_D, would be the only one that gets filtered out)

I was able to get it to work after making a slight modification to your query (using `NOT IN` instead of `IN`):

`?package a :package.
FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?package :platform ?platform. 
                    FILTER (?platform NOT IN(:Platform_1)) }`

Comment: In that case, you can eliminate the double negation by using `FILTER EXISTS` and `?platform IN...`. Means the same thing but probably easier to understand.