# Applying a filter to connected vertices recursively (SPARQL)

Tags: sparql, rdf, amazon-neptune

This is a follow up question to another [question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66484878/filter-out-vertices-that-have-outgoing-edges-to-other-vertices-that-are-not-in-a) regarding using SPAQRL for RDF to come up with a query that filters out all vertices that have any edges to other vertices that are not in a list of specified values, for which I received [a working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66484982/3543488).

Here is a visual representation of the graph I'm working with, which contains nodes of two separate RDF types (`:package` and `:platform`). In this graph, packages (`:Package_A`, `:Package_B`, `:Package_C`, and `:Package_D`) have outgoing edges to each platform that they require, and the values of the platforms are `:Platform_1:` and `:Platform_2`.

In this follow up, packages can now also depend on other packages, and this is represented on the graph using a `:requires` edge from a `:package` to another `:package` when it has a dependency on it.

[image]

In the above graph, `Package_A` requires both `Package_B` and `Package_C`, while both `Package_B` and `Package_C` require `Package_D`

Here is the data that creates this graph:

```
INSERT DATA {
   :Package_A             rdf:type   :package .
   :Package_B             rdf:type   :package .
   :Package_C             rdf:type   :package .
   :Package_D             rdf:type   :package .

   :Platform_1            rdf:type   :platform .
   :Platform_2            rdf:type   :platform .

   :Package_A             :platform  :Platform_1 .
   :Package_B             :platform  :Platform_1 .
   :Package_C             :platform  :Platform_1 .
   :Package_D             :platform  :Platform_1 . 

   :Package_D             :platform  :Platform_2 .

   :Package_A             :requires  :Package_B .
   :Package_A             :requires  :Package_C .
   :Package_B             :requires  :Package_D .
   :Package_C             :requires  :Package_D .
}
```

I'm able to query this graph to filter out all `:package` vertices that have any edges to other vertices that are not in a list of specified values.
For example, in the case of this specified singleton list: `[:Platform_1]`, the following query filters out `Package_D` since it contains edges to both `Platform_1` AND `Platform_2` (`Platform_2` is not in the specified list). `Package_A`, `Package_B` and `Package_C` are returned since these packages *only* have edges that lead to `Platform_1`.

```
SELECT * {
    ?package a :package .
     FILTER NOT EXISTS {
         ?package :platform ?platform . 
         FILTER (?platform NOT IN(:Platform_1))
     }
}
```

I'm now trying to expand on this query so that it also filters out any vertex that `:requires` any other package (either directly or transitively) that meets the same criteria and has an outgoing edge to a value that is not in the specified list.

Meaning that in the case of the list `[:Platform_1]`, *all* packages should be filtered out since all packages have at least a transitive `:requires` on `Package_D`, which has a :platform edge to `Platform_2`, which is not in the specified list.

In the case of the list `[:Platform_1, :Platform_2]`, all package vertices should be returned since all package vertices only have edges connecting to `Platform_1` and `Platform_2`.

I have attempted to use the recursive operator `*` as a way to get all transitive `:requires` paths, and apply the same filter above to it. However, this does not work when specifying the list `[:Platform_1]` as the results of this query still contain `Package_A`, `Package_B` and `Package_C`:

```
SELECT * {
    ?package a :package .
     FILTER NOT EXISTS {
         ?package :requires* ?requires .
         ?package :platform ?platform . 
         FILTER (?platform NOT IN(:Platform_1))
     }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas how I could construct a query that filters out all vertices that have any edges to other vertices that are not in a list of specified values AND also filters out any vertex that has a `:requires` edge (either direct or transitive) that leads to another vertex that meets the same criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very thought-provoking question.
In your query you want to filter out any packages that depend transitively on other packages that are have a platform 'outside' of a list of approved platforms.

The following query will work:

```
SELECT * {
    ?package a :package .
     FILTER NOT EXISTS {
         ?package :requires* ?requirement .
         ?requirement :platform ?platform .
         FILTER (?platform NOT IN(:Platform_1))
     }
}
```

The difference with your query is that it is the requirement that has the platform, as opposed to the package. The `*` will take care of the case when there are no requirements (i.e. Package D), as well as when we look at the platform of the package itself.

For brevity, you may express the above query like this when you are not interested in the list of requirements:

```
SELECT * {
        ?package a :package .
         FILTER NOT EXISTS {
             ?package :requires*/:platform ?platform . #Notice the /.
             FILTER (?platform NOT IN(:Platform_1))
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed explanation about `*` vs `+` as well as the issue with my initial query.
I tried your query, and it looks like that although it correctly yields no results when the filter is `?platform NOT IN(:Platform_1)`, I would expect it to return _all_ four packages when the filter is `?platform NOT IN(:Platform_1, :Platform_2)` because all packages have :platform edges that only lead to the list `[:Platform_1, :Platform_2]`, while this query only returns `:Package_D` when the list `[:Platform_1, :Platform_2]` is provided.

Comment: It seems like this query will filter out any package that has _any_ `:requires` edge at all, correct?

Comment: I think perhaps my original question wasn't clear on explaining how the the filter rule should work. I'm looking for a query that will filter out any vertex that contains a `:platform` edge that leads to a Platform value that is not in a provided list (e.g `[:Platform_1, :Platform_2]`) AND also filters out any vertices that have any `:requires` edge that either directly or transitively leads to another vertex that has a `:platform` that is not in this list (rather than filtering out anything with a `:requires` edge at all)

Comment: I think I understand now, thanks for explaining. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I edited the answer. I'm not sure if I should add the old one again, as it seemed to be somewhat useful. I have saved it on my computer just in case. I'd be grateful for guidance.

Comment: Thank you! The updated answer works in all cases :) The old answer is definitely useful though in terms of explaining how a "`!A AND !B`" query is supposed to work..Almost tempted to post it as a separate question so that it could have its own answer for others who may be curious about that. Anyways, I am choosing this as the accepted answer. Thanks again!